# tkinter rendering wrong RGB shade in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, tkinter, rgb

I am using tkinter in Python (3.5.1). The problem is that actual RGB values are not corresponding to the RGB in tkinter.

For example in this code:

```
import tkinter
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(bg="white")
root.mainloop()
```

It works as expected. However if I replace "white" with "#255255255" the background is grey. And same happens with other widgets too.

So I read the color manual docs on tkinter site, and as per the table this RGB corresponded to "grey100".
Why is it different?
I need the actual correspondence of RGB. Am I doing something wrong, or do I needs external calibration to achieve so ?

Comment: 'tkinter site' is ambiguous and should be linked to an actual url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters in '#rrggbb' (8 bits per pixel) and '#rrrgggbbb' (12 bits per pixel) color strings are interpreted as hexadecimal, not decimal. '#ffffff' and '#fffffffff' are white. 0x255 is 597 while 0xfff is 4095, so '#255255255' turn each pixel on about 15%, so the result appears nearly black.

Comment: Thank You Terry. Was totally unaware of the fact.
Converting the RGB into HEX before passing, makes all my color transitions perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"#255255255"` is being used as `"#RRRGGGBBB"`, with each one in **hexadecimal**. The proper RGB string for pure white would be any of:

- `#FFF`
- `#FFFFFF`
- `#FFFFFFFF`
- `"white"`

Tkinter's colors are always in hexadecimal- 255/255/255 is slightly more than 1/8 full white, since `2` is 14 less than `F`.